# ElasticSearch query is suddenly not giving correct result

Tags: elasticsearch

Our elasticsearch queries were working perfectly fine till 2 days ago, a simple bool query is not returning correct result now..

http://your_es_ip:9200/index_name/_search

```
`{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ref_partner_id.keyword": {
                            "value": "MOCP013141"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}`
```

Sample doc:

```
`{"_index":"credit_line_applications","_type":"_doc","_id":"WRCL0014686","_version":4,"_seq_no":8756,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{"ref_partner_id":"MOCP013141"}}`
```

**_explain** API returns this:

```
    "matched": false,
    "explanation": {
        "value": 0.0,
        "description": "User requested \"match_none\" query.",
        "details": []
    }
}
```

i have tried running different bool queries but getting no result at all..

Comment: What is your index mapping?

Comment: it has since been changed but ifor this field i have noted down the mapping:
"ref_partner_id":{"type":"keyword"} @dcolazin

Comment: Did you try using only "term": { "ref_partner_id": { "value": "MOCP013141" }} (without "keyword" in the field name)?

Comment: Yeah i did, it did not work.  @dcolazin

Answer (score -1):

The `"size": 0` means return no document. Just increase it.

**Note: By default, size set to 10, which means sort by score and get the first 10 documents.**

[image]

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "credit_line_applications", "_id" : "WRCL0014686" } }
{ "ref_partner_id":"MOCP013141" }
```

---

```
GET /credit_line_applications/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ref_partner_id.keyword": {
                            "value": "MOCP013141"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
      "*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting zero Hits in the response.. size parameter as zero will only return the metadata not the whole data, the value of Hits is zero

Comment: If you want to see the whole data you can use `_source` or `fields`.

Comment: Even if I want to see the whole data, the query is returning zero hits... so 
data:[] @MusabDogan